# Why do most image processing gems for ruby require more then just a gem?

Tags: ruby, image-processing

I am new to image processing in Ruby so I figured I would start out with something easy, resizing a bunch of photos to make thumbnails. I found several possible solutions including Rmagick, and Ruby-vips. I know there a more out there, but my question is why do these tools need additional installs to work? (RMagick gem requires ImageMagick program etc)

Comment: Because the gems (ruby code) leverage or "wrap" the *existing* native (eg. C or C++) executable libraries available. Significant amounts of work has already been put into these - and C/C++ is *much* better/faster than Ruby for bit twiddling which is required for image manipulations - so the libraries/program suites are reused, which has the side-effect of making them dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your example of RMagick and ImageMagick, each one focuses on a separate responsibility. First, ImageMagick is a (vast) library of image manipulation capabilities. Resizing is one teeny portion. I assume you've looked it up and seen all the things it can do. Second, RMagick is a Ruby-specific front end to simplify using ImageMagick specifically for Ruby programmers. There will be other similar libraries for other langauges.

Why are they separate? Image manipulation requires oodles of specialized code which needs to process as efficiently as possible (speed, memory size, etc.). Such libraries tend to be written in C, or various flavors thereof. While it is not difficult to install ImageMagick, and write your own Ruby front end for it, it's not something most people want to do. Instead they hope someone else has already done it (RMagick), and they use just that.

Me, since most projects use so little of ImageMagick, I prefer to write my own front end for the ImageMagick commands I actually use, and with APIs dedicated to the processes I use the most often. I wouldn't suggest everyone do that, but it can be done.

Many gems are going to specialize in one focused purpose which solves a particular missing piece to a puzzle as they see it. If someone has already written a well-tested library X, and someone else has written Z, then if you need Y to glue them together in some way, you're likely to use X, use Z, and just write the Y piece. If you think Y might be useful to someone else, you can publish Y as a gem.

Another guy comes along, and wants Y, and finds out he needs X and Z too. Normal.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Do you have any suggestions about what gem I should use for image resizing, or should I just use ImageMagick?....I would like to avoid installing the dependencies if possible

Comment: 'Fraid not. I've used IM for many years now (10+?), haven't even looked for something else.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "image resizing" what kind of images are you talking about? GIFs? JPEGs? PNGs? PDFs? BMPs? All those are different kinds of images and require different code to resize them. What algorithm do you want to use for resizing? ImageMagick can use dozens of different algorithms to resize your image depending on what kind of image it is. Blueprints are very different from photographs, for example. What you want to optimize for, speed, image quality, file size? Are you making your image bigger or smaller? It makes a difference.

You said you wanted to start with "something easy" but this ain't it. Image processing is a very hard problem. ImageMagick has been around since before Linux (check it out) and is really, really good at what it does. Yes, it's got a lot of dependencies and it's hard to install. Image processing is for grown-ups. Don't jump in if the water's too deep for you.